# APFS technical documentation

Tags: filesystem, apfs, documentation

Is any technical documentation available for Apple's new File System. By technical, I mean File System's internal structures, File allocation block etc.
If Apple has not released any documentation, did someone tried to reverse engineer it?

Comment: *If Apple has not released any documentation, did someone tried to reverse engineer it?*  This is unclear.  Reverse engineer it ***how***?  What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I am trying to write a recovery software for APFS. I need to know how this filesystem stores its files. How it manages its boot blocks, volume header, directory structure and file allocation.

Comment: I am trying to find something like this for APFS: http://dubeiko.com/development/FileSystems/HFSPLUS/tn1150.html

Answer (score 4):

> ## [Apple File System Developer Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/APFS_Guide/Introduction/Introduction.html)
>
> Apple File System is a new, modern file system for iOS, macOS, tvOS, and watchOS. It is optimized for Flash/SSD storage and features strong encryption, copy-on-write metadata, space sharing, cloning for files and directories, snapshots, fast directory sizing, atomic safe-save primitives, and improved file system fundamentals.

See also Apple's [File System Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010672).

Additionally, this blog [APFS – A Backup Software Developer’s Perspective](https://macdaddy.io/apfs-backup-software-developers-perspective/)  makes mention of APFS already being [reverse engineered](https://blog.cugu.eu/post/apfs/).

Comment: I have already gone these documents/articles. I am trying to find something like this: http://dubeiko.com/development/FileSystems/HFSPLUS/tn1150.html

Answer (score 3):

Apple has released documentation for APFS. It's a little sparse, but most of the critical information should be there.

https://developer.apple.com/support/apple-file-system/Apple-File-System-Reference.pdf